# Connection to the docker container with PostgreSQL using boost::asio library

Tags: c++, docker, boost, boost-asio, docker-container

This is my first question, so please dont hate me a lot for my inexperience.
I tried to write a simple messenger in the stack of technologies: c++, cmake, qt, boost, docker.

**The concept is**:

1. client - can connect to the server and exchange messages with it
2. server - can accept clients' connections and process them, connect to DB in Docker and of cause exchange messages with all of them
3. DB - the "vanilla" (primal) docker-container with running PostgreSQL inside

I wrote the main part of this components, ran DB and tried to connect my server to DB, but every time I did this - nothing happened (error of connection catched). May be I'm stupid, but I couldn't find anything about my problem anywhere. So I decided to ask here.
this is the implementation of connection:

**class**:

```
class Server : public ServerI {
    private:
        socket_ptr _sock;
        io_service & _service;

        size_t _port{};
        ip::address _address;
        ip::tcp::endpoint _ep;

        std::map<size_t, Session &> _sessions;
    public:
        Server(io_service & service) : _service(service) {}
        ~Server() {
            // "kill" all threads (sessions)
            for (auto & s : _sessions) {
                s.second.th.detach();
            }
        }

        void waitForConnection() override;
        void sessionHandler() override;
        void connectToDB(const ConnectionInfo &c_inf = {"", 0}) override;

    private:

        void setEndpoint(const ip::tcp::endpoint & ep);

        void connect();
        void disconnect();

        size_t request(const std::string & target);
        std::string getResponse();
    };
```

**funcs:**

```
void Server::connectToDB(const ConnectionInfo &c_inf) {
        std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep( ip::address::from_string(c_inf.s_ip), c_inf.port);
        std::cout << ep.address() << " " << ep.port() << std::endl;
        this->setEndpoint(ep);
        std::cout << _ep << " " << _port << std::endl;
        try {
            this->connect();
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout << "connection error" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //===============================//

    void Server::setEndpoint(const ip::tcp::endpoint & ep) {
        _ep = ep;
        _port = ep.port();
        _address = ep.address();
        std::cout << "ep, port, address are set" << std::endl;
        _sock = socket_ptr(new ip::tcp::socket(_service));
    }

    void Server::connect() {
        try {
            // just a hardcode - tried to debug this
            _sock->connect(_ep);
        } catch (boost::system::system_error & err) {
            std::cerr << "connection error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
```

**example of usage**:

```
server->connectToDB({"0.0.0.0", 5432});
```

**Docker**:
I just pressed run button on the corresponding imagine in the containers menu
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpUi5.png)

Also later I used some guid and this is logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd8U7.png)

accept any advices

**What I've done**:
Tried to hardcode address and debug, but error has been caused by socket lib function, so I dont know what shall I do.
May be it's not enough to just run container,  and I have to set up DB or whatever.
May be my ip/port format for connection is wrong.

Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "all interfaces"; it doesn't really make sense to make outbound connections to it, only to use it as a bind address to accept inbound connections.  You mention Docker; what parts of this are running in containers?  If 0.0.0.0 is interpreted as "localhost", that tends to mean "the current container" and not one of the other parts.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I'm noob in Docker now. 0.0.0.0 is just ip, I found in the inspect page in the container

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 with port 5432, but no one works!

Comment: Is the server code running in a container?  The database?  Do you have the `docker-compose.yml` or a set of `docker run` commands you used to start containers?  In a Docker context all of those 127... addresses are probably not correct, and you should never need to look up the container-private IP addresses.

Comment: Seems like you are reinventing the wheal. Please read [QT Manual to work with PostrgressSQ](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html)

Comment: @DavidMaze,
> Do you have the docker-compose.yml?
no, I don't
> Is the server code running in a container? The database?
DB
>  you should never need to look up the container-private IP addresses.
but what shall I do?

Comment: @VictorGubin, what is that? I've never used Qt DB utils.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I see that your call:
`server->connectToDB({"0.0.0.0", 32769});`
always result in hardcoded connect:
`_sock->connect(ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("localhost:32769"), 5432)); //(_ep);`
And, the from_string-method only accepts a host address, not the colon-separated port that you provide, so remove that part.

Comment: Ok. this was a good advice, but, unfortunately, nothing gonna change. It still doesn't work.
'''
connection error: connect: ��������� ����� ��� ������ ��������� ������� [system:10049 at ...
'''

Comment: So, which address and which port are you actually trying to connect to?
Also, verify that something (PostgreSQL) is listening on that interface and port, using for example netstat. On linux: netstat -lnt